# Merge two data frames by matching one column from the first data frame with two columns from the second data frame

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm working with two data frames :

```
df1 = {'Metropolitan area': {0: 'New York City',
  1: 'Los Angeles',
  2: 'San Francisco Bay Area',
  3: 'Chicago',
  4: 'Dallas–Fort Worth'},
 'token_nhl': {0: 'Devils',
  1: 'Ducks',
  2: 'Sharks',
  3: 'Blackhawks',
  4: 'Stars'}}
```

```
df2 = {'NHL': {0: 'team1', 1: 'team2', 2: 'team3', 3: 'team4', 4: 'team5'},
 'token_nhl': {0: 'Devils', 1: 'Ducks', 2: 'x', 3: 'Stars', 4: 'Sharks'},
 'token_nhl1': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'Blackhawks', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}}
```

I'm trying to merge them, but I'd like to match the values of the 'token_nhl' columns in df1 with both 'token_nhl' and 'token_nhl1' in df2, so whenever I don't find a value in 'token_nhl', I go look for it in 'token_nhl1',and then the resulting data frame would be :

```
{'NHL': {0: 'team1', 1: 'team2', 2: 'team3', 3: 'team4', 4: 'team5'},
 'token_nhl_left': {0: 'Devils', 1: 'Ducks', 2: 'x', 3: 'Stars', 4: 'Sharks'},
 'token_nhl1_left': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'Blackhawks', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'},
 'token_nhl_right': {0: 'Devils',1: 'Ducks',2: 'Blackhawks',3: 'Stars',4: 'Sharks'}}
```

Comment: here, 'x' means to nan value?

Comment: It just means a random value we don't care about

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to merge two times:

1: renaming columns, becuase after merge pandas is not giving two different columns

```
df1 = df1.rename(columns = {"token_nhl":"token_nhl_left"})
df2 = df2.rename(columns = {"token_nhl":"token_nhl_right"})
# creating variables
left_on = "token_nhl_left"
right_on1 = "token_nhl_right"
right_on2 = "token_nhl1"
left_columns = df1.columns
```

2. merge-1

   ```
    df_temp1 = pd.merge(left = df1, right = df2, left_on = left_on, right_on = right_on1, how = 'left')
   ```
3. merge-2

   ```
    df_temp2 = pd.merge(left = df_temp1[pd.isna(df_temp1[right_on1])][left_columns], right = df2, left_on = left_on, right_on = right_on2, how = 'left')
   ```
4. concat

   ```
    df_final = pd.concat([df_temp1[pd.notna(df_temp1[right_on1])]  , df_temp2])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this question involves two steps.

1 - Create a chunk of code to bring the desired information to a list:

```
lis = []
for (y,w) in zip(list(df2['token_nhl']), list(df2['token_nhl1'])):
    if y in list(df1['token_nhl']):
        lis.append(y)
    else:
        lis.append(w)
```

2 - Assign that list to a new data frame with all other needed data. After that, rename columns:

```
df3 = df2.assign(token_nhl_right=lis)
df3.rename(columns={'token_nhl':'token_nhl_left' ,'token_nhl1':'token_nhl1_left'})
```